# Update statements taking too long

Tags: performance, sqlperformance

I have to update a column value (real time value) for all the rows in a table
I am using simple update statement in a loop

```
for (i = 1; i < totalRows; i++)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("update [dbo].[real]  set rtv= " + engValues[i] + ",[DateTimeR] = '" + DateTime.Now + "' where [ID]='" + i+ "' ",connection))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

It takes around 10 to 15 seconds to update the entire table which contains only about 700 records!
However i need to get it done every second?

Comment: What is your loop for?

Comment: Don't create new SqlCommands for each update. Don't concatenate SQL strings, use parameters. Don't send numbers as strings. Don't rely on a DateTime being in a proper string format always on every environment. Use transactions.

Comment: @PM for loop is to iterate in all the rows of the table

Comment: @Sami sorry i don't get the "use transactions"

Comment: You can create a transaction and do all updates inside it. Usually the database then only changes the actual data files when it's committed. If you send single updates the database has to update the files after each statement. More information about transactions with your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Sami no difference in performance by using transactions